# Is there a way to regenerate the target directory in leiningen?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

My target directory has been `rm`ed in Linux - does Leiningen offer a way to regenerate it?

Comment: You  mean,  other  than  rebuilding  the  project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just running `lein run` should cause your project rebuild, thereby recreating the `target` directory.